# jQuery validation - Remove error label when correct

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the [jQuery validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) and I have setup my errorPlacement such that the label will fade and animate in nicely but I cannot seem to find out what callback I need to use to do the reverse i.e. when the field is valid how do I remove the error in a similar fasion?

I have tried using the success function but to no avail. The error just disappears once valid...

Code snippet

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    error.appendTo(element.parent().parent().find(".propertyFeedback"));
    error.css({ "margin-left": "-10px", opacity: 0 });
    error.animate({ "margin-left": "0px", opacity: 1 });
},
success: function (error, element) {
    error.show().animate({ "margin-left": "-10px", opacity: 0 });
}
```

Comment: well if you use the same code with reversed properties in the "valid" callback, doesn't it work?

Comment: What callback function do I use though? `errorPlacement` gets called when the error is placed, but what callback gets called when it passes validation?

Comment: well..what validation system are you using?

Comment: The jQuery validation plugin, updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you call http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid ?

So you need something like `if ( $("#myform").valid() ) {}`